# Generate Layout Inside a Table Row Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to add a Linear Layout inside a programmatically generated Table Row layout. The linear layout never seems to show. I have tried setting the width and height in the program yet nothing helped.

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.info_table);

TableRow row=new TableRow(getContext());
        row.setBackgroundColor(RED);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                        (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int leftMargin=20;
        int topMargin=20;
        int rightMargin=20;
        int bottomMargin=10;

        tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
        row.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

        TextView address = new TextView(getContext());
        address.setMinimumWidth(320);
        address.setMaxWidth(320);
        address.setText("Rating");



        address.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        address.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,16);

        row.addView(address);
        View dummyView = new View(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams dummyParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,300);
        dummyParams.weight = 1f;
        dummyView.setLayoutParams(dummyParams);
        dummyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);            
        row.addView(dummyView);
        row.bringChildToFront(dummyView);

        ll.addView(row,0);
```

I can see only the red color being set by the row but not the black color being set by the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below example, you can create child view in parent view : 
my code working in this manner may be it helps you .

```
 LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(this);             
            linear.setLayoutParams(new 
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableRowParams.addView(linear);
```